# Why does perl complain about locales?

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian, locale

This thread is not a duplicate to [locale not found/setting locale failed - what should I do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110757/locale-not-found-setting-locale-failed-what-should-i-do) because

- the file `/etc/locale.gen` has uncommented the line `en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8` which should sufficient
- no `localepurge` is installed

I get strange `perl: warning: Setting locale failed` in all Linux kernel things etc

```
masi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo a2enmod rewrite && a2enmod headers && a2enmod ssl
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_TIME = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
Module rewrite already enabled

# https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/287622/16920
masi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo deluser -remove-home pi
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_PAPER = "fi_FI.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "fi_FI.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "fi_FI.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "fi_FI.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "fi_FI.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "fi_FI.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "fi_FI.UTF-8",
    LC_TIME = "fi_FI.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "fi_FI.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
/usr/sbin/deluser: The user `pi' does not exist.
```

### Solution

I had `en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8` only enabled in `/etc/locale.gen`. I should have there only enabled `en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8` because of other commands run for it. So I uncommended GB and added US and everything work now

```
masi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo vim /etc/locale.gen

masi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo locale-gen 
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  en_US.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.

masi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo a2enmod rewrite && a2enmod headers && a2enmod ssl
Module rewrite already enabled
Module headers already enabled
Considering dependency setenvif for ssl:
Module setenvif already enabled
Considering dependency mime for ssl:
Module mime already enabled
Considering dependency socache_shmcb for ssl:
Module socache_shmcb already enabled
Module ssl already enabled
```

System: Raspbian Jessie
Hardware: Raspberry Pi 3 b

Comment: Raspbian is just a rebranded Debian, but `/etc/locale.gen` shouldn't be empty. Did you select both `en_US.UTF-8` and `fi_FI.UTF-8` in `dpkg-reconfigure locales`?

Comment: You need to select all the locales that you use.

Comment: If you're running this on a small embedded system, I'm guessing you don't have a very complete set of language files installed. If en_GB.UTF-8 worked and en_US.UTF-8 failed, I'm going to guess that this is what's happening to you. You'll need to go back and get the language packs you want. And this does look like a dupe of that other question.

Comment: @EdwardFalk I found the solution, see the body. It was a human error. I had no `en_US` enabled in `/etc/locale.gen`. Those commands suggested in the other thread do NOT throubleshoot this very common human source location. You can have as many locales enabled in the file as you want. I had only one. Mistake was that I thought the commands automatically handle `/etc/locale.gen` but they do not. In this way, this thread is unique. You should include `/etc/locale.gen` and check all wanted locales in the troubleshoot strategy.